# Wider points cuxfilter / Datashader scatter?

Tags: jupyter, bokeh, holoviews, datashader, rapids

How can I get wider points to display in this `datashader.scatter` plot of cuxfilter? Or less whitespace between columns? This is a scatter plot of `passenger_count` (x) vs `tip_amount` (y) on some TLC yellow cab trip data.

[image: How to make the points in chart_2 wider?]

The goal is to have something similar to this next chart which is representing the same thing with `holoviews.Scatter`:

[image: Desired outcome to look similar to this.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at the Heatmap chart(https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuxfilter/stable/charts/datashader_charts.html#heat-map-chart)?

You can control shape of the point using the point_shape attribute(circle, square, rect_vertical, rect_horizontal), and point_size attribute.